# store m/d/y (01/1/2001 example) string as DATE

Tags: php, mysql, string, date, date-format

When I try to `SELECT CAST('01/1/2001' AS DATE)`, it always returns `NULL` (as an example of how I can't get this to work).  I'm trying to `INSERT` data created in this format.

How can I store dates of this format in a `DATE` column?

Please note that the day never has a prefix `0` while the month does if it is less than `10`.

Comment: If you're within PHP...could you re-cast the date format into an unambiguous MySQL date format using `substr` or `preg_match` before querying the DB?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I'd love to, I just have no idea how.  PHP grabs the data and stores it in MySQL.

Comment: Please do not store dates in formats like this. You may think that `10/12/2013` is the 12th of October, but to me it the 10th of December. It causes confusion between people, and more importantly the computer can't guess which one you mean. Always use `yyyy-mm-dd` when storing dates to ensure that it's unambiguous. Feel free to present them to the user in whatever localised format you like (or preferably that the user likes), but inside your program you should always stick to `yyyy-mm-dd`, or a datetime object.

Comment: @Spudley i have no control over the data source.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy - the data source is out of your control, but convert it to an unambiguous format as soon as it enters your program. As I said: Accept input in the user's preferred format, but use a sensible format internally.

Comment: @Spudley this is all personal, so i'm going with mysql's `DATE`; professionally, i always push unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL function `STR_TO_DATE()` like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('01/1/2012',  '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Of course edit the format according to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

just use this code

```
 $date="01/1/2013";

date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store it in that format. It's not very usable that way and you will regret it later when you need to do more then just read it.

Store it as a `date` data type...

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-j-Y","01/1/2001"); 
$new_format = $date->format("Y-m-d"); // 2001-01-01
```

...and then format it when you select it:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%m/%l/%Y") AS date // 01/1/2001
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be quite an answer, but if you know the exact order (d/m/Y), you can do it as follows:

```
list($month,$day,$year) = explode("/","01/1/2013");
$date = $year."-".str_pad($month,2,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."-".str_pad($day,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

You can then safely use the MySQL date format for comparisons and general checks rather than using pseudo-comparisons using VARCHAR. Not just this, but you'll also benefit from DATETIME as an index.

Comment: do i do `"'.$date.'"` or `".$date."` for the `VALUE`?

Comment: Depends. Do you parametrize? If not, you should.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple way of doing it:

```
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/","01/1/2013");
$time = mktime(0,0,0,intval($month),intval($day),intval($year));
$date_format = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```